# How to get date information from Google Static Maps Api satellite images?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

When downloading satellite images using the Google Static Maps API, is there also a way to get some metadata, for example when (year, month, day) the satellite image was taken?

Im downloading relatively small images (no more than 100 square meters most of the time).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently this is not possible.

There is a feature request in Google issue tracker that you can see at

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35824769

Unfortunately, it looks like Google didn't set high priority on this task. I would suggest starring the feature request to add your vote and subscribe to notifications.